Can Firefox/Chrome developer tools' console.log truncation be turned off?
Is there a browser setting to increase the length of or disable the dev tools' console.log truncation length?
I'm asking this question because I'm looking for a workaround to this Firefox bug that also exists in Google Chrome that doesn't require a change in code.
I'll explain the bug first. If you run this snippet:


function myConsoleLog(param) {
  console.log(param, param.x);
}
const xObj = { x: false };
myConsoleLog(xObj);
xObj.x = true;



you will see this output:

If you open Firefox/Chrome developer tools and run the snippet, it ostensibly prints the same output, but there is an icon on the left that allows you to expand the object. Note what prints when you click to expand:

In other words, the expanded content renders the current state, not the state at the time of console.log.
If I could console.log the entire object without needing to expand, I'd never need to expand, helping me avoid a class of misleading debug information. But by default, Firefox and Chrome truncate the output of console.log; for example, if you run this snippet:


function nextChar(c) {
  return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}

const bigObj = {};
for (let i = "a".charCodeAt(0); i <= "z".charCodeAt(0); i++) {
  bigObj[String.fromCharCode(i)] = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
}

console.log(bigObj);



the output looks like this:

but if you run this in the Firefox dev console, it is truncated like this:

I'm aware of the answers in Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects? but I'm asking if there's a way to see the full output without modifying my code.

Maybe custom formatters for devtools may help, but I'd write a trivial extension that patches console.log at document_start in the MAIN world (method 5) e.g. console.log = new Proxy(console.log, {apply: (fn,_,args)=>fn(...deepCopy(args))}) using one of the popular deepCopy libraries.

Have you tried just replacing console.log() with a function that makes a copy of the object and logs the copy? That way when inspecting the object in the console later you have a snapshot that's of the object as it was at the time it was logged, rather than the live version? That's easy to do with just a little bit of code. Depending on how you do it, it can require no changes to any other part of your code, other than dropping in those few lines. It's something that I routinely do to get around this issue.

@Makyen I've done that for other reasons, but I'm never sure if I'm doing it the right way. I've seen people use bind/apply and others just reassign to console.log.

At least in Firefox the maximum number of properties shown is hardcoded to 10. And I'm pretty sure in Chrome it's the same.
Though there shouldn't be a need to change that number. Instead, you can use logpoints to output the current value of a variable if you don't want to change your code (see the Chrome DevTools documentation or the Firefox DevTools documentation for how to add them).
In addition to that, the Chrome DevTools provide a feature called "live expressions" that always display the current value of a variable.
If the properties within your object or the items within your array exceed the maximum number of items displayed in the preview (without expanding it), then you can use JSON.stringify() to output the whole structure as a string.

Wow, amazing stuff. DOM change breakpoints and Function breakpoints are especially useful. Neither docs explicitly state this, but logpoints persist across browser refreshes.
